# Win API to disable Windows Dynamic Lock (aka Windows Goodbye)

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

I am trying to temporarily disable the Windows Dynamic Lock while running long operations on my computer when I don't want the computer to sleep, lock or turn turn off the screen. I have found a way to do this by toggling the following Windows registry key between `1` and `0` but I'd prefer to use a Windows API to make the update in the event there are other dependencies in which I am unaware of.

`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\EnableGoodbye`

Anyone know which Windows API allows reads and updates to this setting?

*I have had a few people mention `SetThreadExecutionState`, so I am adding a [link to a repo](https://github.com/scottrudy/dontsleep) to show that I am already using that.*

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that there are no APIs for that at all.

Normally application call `SetThreadExecutionState` to bypass poweroff, handle `SC_SCREENSACE` / `SC_MONITORPOWER` to keep display on.

But locking on inactivity is a security feature, so I don't think applications should easily manipulate it. I believe applications should suggest users to disable it manually instead, so that users would explicitly  disable it. I therefore think there's no API.

Comment: That's a good point @alex. I am using the ThreadExecutionState already, but it wasn't enough when that is enabled.